# What options do I have to standardize data?

Tags: r, scale, data-modeling

I am working on a database of about 40 ophthalmological patients from which we obtain 90 variables. These variables are mainly binomial (1 contains this disease/characteristic, 0 does not). So my initial approach was to carry out a univariate analysis to filter out those variables that had a low p value (0.25) and then, using a stepwise method, reduce the number of variables using AIC so that only the significant variables remained in the model.

The thing is that this database comes from a study whose data is relatively poor, many variables have values that do not allow us to carry out the operations without even applying a bias reduction. I use the wonderful [brglm2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brglm2/index.html) package . Thus I have the following formula:

```
glm(respondstotreatment ~ v1+v2+v3..., family = "binomial", data = data, method = brglm2::brglm_fit)
```

So, I realized that there were some observations that had a large number of NAs. I was left with 36 observations and from observations that I obtained, the variables that were numeric I scaled them using the scale() function.

Finally, I obtained a definitive model with only 5 variables and reasonable values. Furthermore, it conforms to the literature and it is possible to interpret it.

The thing is, a few weeks later (today) my boss told me that a value that I put as 0.00 was better to put the real value (my intention was to say that the odds ratio obtained was below 0.001) but she wants the value " exact".

When repeating the analysis following the same steps that I did the previous time, I get different values, and I don't know if it is because the step() method chooses those values in order to be entered, or if I performed some other necessary standardization on the data which I don't remember now.

So I propose to learn more about standardizing data and methods to do it in order to create more robust and replicable methods from now on (and also get out of this mess).

The AIC of my obtained model is 25 , the AIC I can achieve right now is 32. . .

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: this is a stats question, not a programming one, so off topic for here. I voted to migrate it